# How to extend CodeIgniter's alpha_numeric validation rule to have Polish_Signs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

How to extend CodeIgniter's validation form_validation library, so alpha_numeric rule can also include Polish characters like "ęĘóÓąśĄŚżźćŻŹĆńŃ" ?

e.g. I use `'rules' => 'required|alpha_numeric'`

I want it to accept words I typed above too.

How to achieve that?

Comment: please add more details about what have you tried so far to achieve it and what results is it producing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library 
application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

        public function __construct($config = array()){
                parent::__construct($config);
        }

        public function special_character( $str ){
                //\pL stands for any letter \pN for any digit
                return ( ! preg_match("/^([\pL\pN_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
}
```

Comment: This preg_match doesn't work properly for all polish signs. for example str = `ą` = true. And str = `ź` false. @elddenmedio. And it only check for some polish signs, without them in string = False. It has to be all alpha signs + polish signs allowed.

Comment: hi, you can try this `return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-ęĘóÓąśĄŚżźćŻŹĆńŃ ]+$/i', $str);`